# Color specification for one group only

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working on a script for plotting volcano plots for a specific number of groups that the user specifies, i.e. if he wants to have five groups colored, the script modifies the data set accordingly with a new column called `color`. All the other observations that are there shouldn't be highlighted specifically, but be grey.

Is it possible to only specify the color of one group while letting ggplot2 choose all the colors for the other groups available?

I couldn't solve this using `scale_color_manual`, since it expects values for all groups!

This image demonstrates my problem, all other features except the groups, i.e. the "Features (all)" group should be grey instead of red, however I want ggplot to color all other groups automatically...

[image: Volcano plot]

Comment: Please provide a small example which demonstrates your problem. But in short, yes. Many things are possible in R.

Comment: Try this example: `ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, col = Species)) + geom_line() + scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "grey", "grey"))`

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue, I want to color only one group specifically, all others automatically...

Comment: Then try identity? `myDat$myCol <- ifelse(myDat$Species == "setosa", "red", "grey"); ggplot(myDat, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, col = myCol)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_identity()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying a custom color palette and sorting the color column solved my problem :)